# storing Google map autocomplete location into db

Tags: google-maps

I have integrated Google map auto complete into my application. When user types koramangala. He will get entire address. This is part of registration.

```
 Can you please guide is it legal to store Google map auto complete address into my application?.

 If it is not legal can any one tell me how i can proceed.(Instead of storing country,city,state all into my database).
```

Thanks and Regards,
Gokul